# Entity Framework has issues with composite key which is part auto generated

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been searching for a while trying to figure this out. I'm trying to create a table with a composite primary key. The first part of the key is also a foreign key to the parent table. The second part is autogenerated on the SQL Server. So, I have a table that should look like this:

```
ParentId ChildId
-------- -------
 1        1
 1        2
 1        3
 2        1
 2        2
 2        3
 2        4
```

The ChildId column is only unique within the context of the ParentId. The values are autogenerated on the server using an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger so that each ChildId has its own sequence.

My issue is that while this works grand within SQL Server, and classic ADO.NET `SqlCommand` statements, Entity Framework does not want to work with this.

If I set the ChildId column's StoreGeneratedPattern to be an Identity then EF generates SQL that looks like this:

```
insert [dbo].[ChildTable]([ParentId], [Name])
values (@0, @1)
select [ChildId]
from [dbo].[ChildTable]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [ParentId] = @0 and [Id] = scope_identity()
```

This just generates an error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException : Store
>   update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of
>   rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities
>   were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
>   ---->
>   System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException : Store update, insert, or
>   delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities
>   may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

However, if I create a test table with a key based on a GUID and set the StoreGeneratedPattern to be an Identity then the SQL generated looks like this:

```
declare @generated_keys table([Id] uniqueidentifier)
insert [dbo].[GuidTable]([Name])
output inserted.[Id] into @generated_keys
values (@0)
select t.[Id]
from @generated_keys as g join [dbo].[GuidTable] as t on g.[Id] = t.[Id]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0
```

And the entity in my application is updated with the value of the GUID that the SQL Server generated.

So, that suggests that the column does not have to be an IDENTITY column in order for the Entity Framework to get a value back, however, since it uses the logical table `inserted` the value of ChildId won't be the value that it was changed to by the trigger. Also, the `inserted` table cannot have an UPDATE operation applied to it to push the values back inside the trigger (Tried that, it said "The logical tables INSERTED and DELETED cannot be updated.")

I feel that I've kind of backed myself in to a corner here, but before I rethink the design is there any way to get the ChildId value(s) back into the application via Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article which offered a suggestion: http://wiki.alphasoftware.com/Scope_Identity+in+SQL+Server+with+nested+and+INSTEAD+OF+triggers

The TL;DR version is that the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` performs a `SELECT` at the end to return the keys. The article was for the loss of the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` value due to the trigger but it also works here too.

So, what I did was this:

The Trigger now now reads

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.IOINS_ChildTable
ON  dbo.ChildTable
  INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Acquire the lock so that no one else can generate a key at the same time.
-- If the transaction fails then the lock will automatically be released.
-- If the acquisition takes longer than 15 seconds an error is raised.
DECLARE @res INT;
EXEC @res = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'IOINS_ChildTable', 
  @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockOwner = 'Transaction', @LockTimeout = '15000',
  @DbPrincipal = 'public'
IF (@res < 0)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Unable to acquire lock to update ChildTable.', 16, 1);
END

-- Work out what the current maximum Ids are for each parent that is being
-- inserted in this operation.
DECLARE @baseId TABLE(BaseId int, ParentId int);
INSERT INTO @baseId
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(c.Id, 0)) AS BaseId, i.ParentId
  FROM  inserted i
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ChildTable c ON i.ParentId = c.ParentId
  GROUP BY i.ParentId

-- The replacement insert operation
DECLARE @keys TABLE (Id INT);
INSERT INTO ChildTable
OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @keys
SELECT 
  i.ParentId, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.ParentId ORDER BY i.ParentId) + b.BaseId 
    AS Id,
  Name
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN @baseId b ON b.ParentId = i.ParentId

-- Release the lock.
EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'IOINS_ChildTable', 
  @DbPrincipal = 'public', @LockOwner = 'Transaction'

SELECT Id FROM @keys
END
GO
```

The Entity Model has the Id column's `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to being `Identity`. This means that when Entity Framework attempts to read the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` it will get the value the `SELECT` statement in the trigger supplied rather than the value its own `SELECT ... SCOPE_IDENTITY()` supplied, which is now in the next result set which EF wasn't expecting and will ignore.

This has some obvious issues.

Because the trigger now selects data to be returned from the trigger it means that other code, say a stored proc, that inserts some data and performs its own select is going to have the data from its own selected pushed out. So if you have code expecting only one result set from a database operation, it now has an additional result set.

If you are only ever going to use the entity framework then this may all be fine. However, I can't say what the future holds so I'm not entirely comfortable with this solution.